# Responsive square and rectangle same height

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using bootstrap 3 to build my responsive site.
I have 2 rows. 3 divs in one row (left side) and one big div on the right side.
Using padding i adjust the 3 divs on the left to be the same size as the big div.
My problem is that i can't make the two rows to be always at the same height.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-24 pull-right">
      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
         <div class="carousel-inner">
           * images *
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-24">
          <ul class="list-unstyled subject_list">
              <li id="" class="subject_button">
                 <div class="">
                    Div 1
                 </div>
              </li>
              <li id="" class="subject_button">
                 <div class="">
                    Div 3
                 </div>
              </li>
              <li id="" class="subject_button">
                 <div class="">
                    Div 3
                 </div>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look into this bootstrap plugin http://www.minimit.com/articles/solutions-tutorials/bootstrap-3-responsive-columns-of-same-height. Btw: there is no class `.col-xs-24` in Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks i'll check it. I customize bootstrap to be 24 columns grid

Comment: I tried this one but unfortunately it will only work if i have one div and not 3 at the side